# open graph story Facebook sharing with IOS with multiple languages support

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-opengraph

for a custom open graph story through IOS SDK, is there a way to specify the language locale to make it work in another language than english ? Thx!

Comment: where you able to make this work? I've made translations but I'm not able to make them work when posting custom stories